# How to append data transfer content at specific location on HTML5 drop event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing HTML5 Drag-And-Drop on my body tag. Images can be dropped at any place. When I drop over a tag (div's, paragraphs, etc) it works correctly. (I really need to prepend at these cases). When I drop over body, it will be placed before all other elements. How can I append data at a specific location (event.clientX and event.clientY) when it's on body tag?

`document.elementFromPoint()` give me BODY tag.

content id is my 'body' tag.

```
$('#content')
    .bind('drop', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var data=event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("Text");          
        $(event.originalEvent.target).prepend(data);
    })

;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the target of the event is the body and give another target in that case:

```
$('#content').bind('drop', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

    if (event.originalEvent.target.id == 'content')
        $('#divForOtherImages').append(data);
    else
        $(event.originalEvent.target).prepend(data);
});
```

Comment: Actually I need to add it on body. This will add data to a specific div. If I drop between 2 paragraphs, I need to add data between.

Comment: Ok, I understood that wrong. In your case, you probably have to get the coordinates from the drop event and check them against the positions of all elements in your body.

Comment: so I need to use `document.elementFromPoint()` beginning on drop coordinates and going back until find a non-body element?